# AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'Wrapper'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, astronomy

This error happens cause I used `from astroNN.models import Galaxy10CNN` and do downgrade Tensorflow to 1.15.2 to prevent the `ImportError: cannot import name 'get_default_session'` but see new error related to attribute 'Wrapper'   `AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'Wrapper'`

Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the keras.layers.wrapper in Tensorflow 1.15 as

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.keras.layers.Wrapper(layer, **kwargs)
```

for more details on the library please find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Wrapper).

Answer (score 0):

With `tensorflow` version 1.15.2 and `astroNN` version 1.0.1 a hacky way is to replace line 15 of the file `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/astroNN/nn/layers.py` (e.g., in linux, with colab)

```
Layer, Wrapper, InputSpec = tf.keras.layers.Layer, tf.keras.layers.Wrapper, tf.keras.layers.InputSpec
```